# program to check whether my wifi is secured(ie WPA2/WEP) in windows c++

Tags: c++, winapi, wep, wpa

Is it possible to check whether my Wi-Fi is secured(ie WPA2/WEP) programmatically in Windows C++?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If you think that your app could refuse to use an unsecured WiFi, you miss the point of public/open WiFi using VPNs.

Comment: @Didier Trosset: I assume the question really means "...whether my _network connection_ is an unsecure WiFi". If you go via VPN, then although unsecured WiFi is the carrier, it's a different network connection. And while it's actually the user's fault if he runs applications that transmit sensitive data over public/open WiFi (what data except public websites is not sensitive, anyway), I can somewhat understand the OP's goodwilled attempt to protect the uncanny user from the most stupid vulnerability. Though "internet" as such isn't secure, there's still different "shades of grey".

Answer (score 2):

From what I recall this is possible through the [native Wi-Fi API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms705969%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and especially via the [WlanHostedNetworkQueryProperty()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd439491.aspx) function when querying for the [WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_SECURITY_SETTINGS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd439507.aspx).